# Mongodb Query for an array with more than word structure

Tags: mongodb

If you have an array in mongodb as follows:

```
"tokens": [
{
  "index": 1,
  "word": "I",
  "originalText": "I",
  "lemma": "I",
  "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
  "characterOffsetEnd": 5,
  "pos": "NNP",
  "ner": "PERSON",
  "before": "",
  "after": " "
},
{
  "index": 2,
  "word": "played",
  "originalText": "played",
  "lemma": "play",
  "characterOffsetBegin": 6,
  "characterOffsetEnd": 11,
  "pos": "VBZ",
  "ner": "O",
  "before": " ",
  "after": " "
},
{
  "index": 3,
  "word": "football",
  "originalText": "football",
  "lemma": "football",
  "characterOffsetBegin": 22,
  "characterOffsetEnd": 24,
  "pos": "IN",
  "ner": "O",
  "before": " ",
  "after": " "
}
]
```

and I want to query this array as follows:

I need to check if the `(word:I)` and `(word which contains word:regex(p.*) and pos:VBZ)` are in this array or not? if yes I need to return that array.

`$elemMatch` didn't help as I search for two conditions in that array `{"word":"I" and ("word":/p.* and "pos":"VBZ")` together and in order

Anyone can help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I get what you want, and it's a little tricky because:

1. If you didn't have the `index` field you would rely on the order of the array elements which is bad practice
2. The solution below is not generic and it will be hard to modify it if you want additional parameters (like more than 2 elements, more complicated regex).

What I wanted to achieve in this solution is to `$filter` the matched elements and check if the filtered indexes are `$subtract` into 1 which means they are in order:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            filtered_tokens: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$tokens',
                    as: 'token',
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            {
                                $eq: ['$$token.word', 'I']
                            },
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        $eq: [{$substr: ['$$token.word', 0, 1]}, 'p']
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $eq: ['$$token.pos', 'VBZ']
                                    }
                                ]                            
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            filtered_tokens: {$size: 2}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            filtered_tokens: {
                $subtract: [
                    {
                        $arrayElemAt: ['$filtered_tokens.index', 1]
                    },
                    {
                        $arrayElemAt: ['$filtered_tokens.index', 0]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            filtered_tokens: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you need, but I think this it what you are looking for:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {
            'tokens.word': 'I'
        },
        {
            tokens: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    word: /p.*/,
                    pos: 'VBZ'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: the problem is in the order right now, I mean if you search for I and after that football, he will give you a result but it shouldn't give any results as the order is I word, played word and then football word. Do you have any comments how I can solve it

Comment: sorry, didn't understand the question. add an example with expected reuslts

Comment: If your search query is [I P*:VBZ] then the result will be the json file and that's right as the words order is I played football but If your search query is [I f*:IN] then he gives me a result but I shouldn't receive any result as I followed by played and not by football

Comment: the order does matter if I search I then p* with pos="VBZ" then that's right the result is I played football which is in the json file but if I search for I then f* with pos="IN" then the expectation is no results found

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I added additional answer, please check